# Order a list of categories by number of entries, key not being set

Tags: templating, array

I have modified the code from [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/order-tags-by-count-e-g-top-10-tags-used) but I'm running into an issue.

```
{% set allCats = craft.categories.group('blogCategories').level(1).find() %}

{% set catArray = {} %}

{% for cat in allCats %}

    {% set catArray = catArray | merge({(cat.id):craft.entries.relatedTo(cat).total() }) %}

{% endfor %}

{% set catArray = catArray|sort|reverse %}

{% for catId, count in catArray %}

    {% set category = craft.categories.id(catId).first() %}

    <li>
        <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }} <span>{{count}}</span></a>
    </li>

{% endfor %}
```

Ive ran a dump on the catArray array and the category id isnt being set as the key, regardless of if I try put brackets around it to protect it, I only get the value in the array.

Comment: Did you try the code that I provided (totally untested from my side) in this other Q/A? Ohh and I think we should better close this thread here and "discuss" your problems over there...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order tags by count - e.g. Top 10 Tags Used](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/order-tags-by-count-e-g-top-10-tags-used)

Comment: Sean, I wonder why I (and you too) put the `cat.id` in brackets? Actually no reason to do this..

Comment: I don't think it's identical. The context is different and the issue I have hasn't been mentioned there. The reason you (and therefore I) have it in parentheses is due to [how Twig treats keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638231/twig-using-variables-as-hash-key). It does work when I use a `category.slug` as a key, but `category.id` does not want to work.

Comment: Yes not really completely a duplicate, but if you are running into problems those exact problems are laying in that other Q/A, too.

Comment: I think the issue isnÄt mentioned there because nobody actually tested the code :( ...I wonder who made those upvotes then, hehe?! Ohh and thanks for reminding me where those brackets come from.

Comment: Strange that it doesn't work, Sean. But I have an idea how it should definitely work! See answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you encounter problems with assigning variables as the keys, what about putting all your values into objects?

```twig
{% set catObjects = [] %}

{% for cat in allCats %}

    {% set catObject = [
        { catId: cat.id, catCount: craft.entries.relatedTo(cat).total()  }
    ] %}

    {% set catObjects = catObjects|merge(catObject) %}

{% endfor %}
```