# Query only Tags wich are not connected to a revision

Tags: craft3, tags, query, revisions

I wrote a query like this:

```
 $query = (new Query())
        ->select('COUNT(elements.id) as count, tags.*')
        ->from('relations')
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tags', '{{relations}}.targetId={{tags}}.id')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'content', '{{content}}.elementId={{tags}}.id')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'elements', '{{elements}}.id={{tags}}.id')
        ->where([
            'elements.enabled' => 1,
            'elements.revisionId' => NULL
        ])
        ->groupBy('{{relations}}.targetId')
        ->orderBy('count DESC');
```

So my intention there is to fetch all tags wich have content and do have `revisionId IS NULL`.

But it never works. I get just all the relations including these one related to elements with a revisionId not null.

Can someone help me in this issue.

I am completely new to craft and use to the symfony query builder wich is kind of different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and posted it [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/order-tags-by-count-e-g-top-10-tags-used/36066#36066) in another issue related to this problem.

Here is my solution (just the code):

```
$query = (new Query())
    ->select([
        '{{relations}}.targetId as id',
        'COUNT({{relations.targetId}}) as count',
        '{{content}}.title as title'
    ])
    ->from('relations')
    ->leftJoin('tags', '{{relations}}.targetId={{tags}}.id')
    ->leftJoin('content', '{{content}}.elementId={{tags}}.id')
    ->leftJoin('elements', '{{elements}}.id={{tags}}.id')
    ->leftJoin('elements source', '{{source}}.id={{relations}}.sourceId')
    ->where([
        '{{elements}}.enabled' => 1,
        '{{source}}.enabled' => 1,
        '{{source}}.revisionId' => NULL,
        '{{source}}.draftId' => NULL,
    ])
    ->groupBy('id, title')
    ->orderBy( 'count DESC, title ASC')
;

$query->limit($limit);

if (is_numeric($limit) && !is_null($limit)) {
    $query->limit($limit);
}

$results = $query->all();

foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    $id = $value['id'];
    $results[$key] = Tag::find()->id($id)->one();
}

return $results;
```