# Best method to handle %20 in tag URLs with multiple words

Tags: tags, tag

On my page of all tags, it works great except for tags that have more than one word.
The URL is replacing the spaces with %20 as one would expect.

http://www.colorcomputergames.com/tags/

I tried using:

```
{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.title | kebab }}
```

This works great in changing the %20 to hyphens.
However, if I click on a tag with multiple words I go to page not found. Makes sense as the system doesn't see that tag.

```
  {% extends "_layout" %}
    {% set title = "Tags" %}
    {% block content %}
    {% for tag in craft.tags.order('title') %}
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.title | kebab }}">{{ tag.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

So next I tried:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}
{% set title = "Tags" %}
{% block content %}
{% for tag in craft.tags.order('title') %}
    <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.title | url_encode }}">{{ tag.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But that wasn't ideal either.

What is the best way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update.

After looking at the tag model a little more closely, it looks like tags have both a `title` and `slug` — so if you use the slug to construct your url then you shouldn't have that problem.

For your tag index:

```
<ul>
    {% for tag in craft.tags.order('title') %}
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.slug }}">{{ tag.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In your tag index page (assuming you are using the `tag` token in your custom route):

```
{% set tagEntry = craft.tags.group('myTagGroup').slug(tag).first %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tagEntry).order('title').limit(null) %}
```

Comment: I modified my original code based on the answer here (http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/881/how-can-i-create-a-visually-weighted-tag-cloud/) I then tried your code with the newer code. I have the following, and while it replaces the spaces with hyphens, I still get 404 errors with tags containing two words.

Comment: My mistake. First, it looks like tags have a slug that is kebab case by default. And secondly, I think that you will need a tag model to use in `relatedTo(tag)`. I updated the answer... see if that works better.