# How to display number of entries for a tag and not display if no entries?

Tags: tags, relatedto, count

I want to be able to display the number of entries that have a tag. Like:

Fruit (9)
Vegetables (4)

I also want to avoid displaying any tags without any related entries.

My code right now looks like this:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}
{% set title = "Tags" %}
{% block content %}
{% for tag in craft.tags.order('title') %}
    <li>}<a href="{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.title}}">{{ tag.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
{% set tags = craft.tags.limit(null).relatedTo(craft.entries.limit(null)).order('title') %}

{% for tag in tags %}
    <a href="/tags/{{ tag.slug }}">{{ tag.title }} (craft.entries.relatedTo(tag).total())</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Note that if you have a significant amount of tags, the above could be a costly affair, performance wise – [consider alternative approaches](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/884/1098).